# Subgroup test proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I know that there are many posts about this but I have questions that about these proofs that I don't understand. Consider the following theorem:

Let G be a group and H a non-empty subset of G. If $ab\in H$ when $a,b\in H$ and $a^{-1}\in H$ when $a\in H$, then H is a subgroup of H.

So the only givens are that G is a group and that H is a non-empty subset of G. Since we are told $H\neq \varnothing$ , we can deduce that there exists at least one element in H $x_{0}$. What I don't understand is how do we know that this arbitrary element is an identity of H? Im not convinced that becuase $\exists x\in H$ that we can let $x=a \land x=b$ and that then $ab^{-1} = xx^{-1}=e$ (e = identity element).

Comment: You don't know that whatever group element $x$ that you prove is in $H$ will be the identity element. But, you know that, whenever $a \in H$, then $a^{-1} \in H$ (by some other proof), so $x^{-1}$ also lies in $H$. You also know that, because $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are two elements of $H$, their product $xx^{-1}$ is in $H$ (we know that, for **any** $a, b \in H$ we choose, their product $ab$ is in $H$, including the case $a = x$ and $b = x^{-1}$). The product $xx^{-1}$ is the identity, by definition of inverses.

Comment: @TheoBendit So when i am given the proof for the theorem, it is assumed that H is a group and then the justifications for why follow? 

As a follow up question, When i am given an example to prove that a subset of a group is a subgroup, do we still assume the subset is a group?

Comment: The theorem tells you that given a subset $H$ of a group $G$ what you need to verify to show that $H$ is a subgroup.  It just has to be a group in its own right under the multiplication from $G$.  In general to show a set S is a group, you need to show several things and in this case you get one "for free".

Comment: And to show these "several things" we are essentially using the set $\left\langle a \right\rangle = \left\{ a\in G | a^{n} \land n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ ? (for some a in G)

Comment: A suggestion on style is far less use of formal logic symbols, for example $\{a\in G|a^n\space\text{for all}\space n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is better here.

Comment: What definition of "subgroup" are you using? There's a bunch of equivalent ones. Your proof will depend on which . . .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-step subgroup test "IFF" condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296262/two-step-subgroup-test-iff-condition)

Answer (score 3):

This is a **comment** about the "non-empty" condition in the subgroup test for $H \subseteq G$, as formulated by most authors. This condition is not helpful in many ways (both with regards to mathematical practice and teaching), and instead it should be replaced by the condition $e \in H$.

Here is why:

- When you are asked to prove that a subset $H \subseteq G$ is non-empty, you have to look for *some* element in $H$. So you have to look through all the elements of $G$ and test if one of these elements lies in $H$. This is definitely harder than only checking that *one specific* element is contained in $H$, namely the identity $e$.
- For example, consider the subgroup $\{{\small\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}} : ad-bc = 1\}$ of $ \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Instead of fiddling around with random elements $a,b,c,d$ which satisfy $ad-bc=1$, it is easier to just see that $\small{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}$ belongs to the set.
- Even if you know that $e \in H$ is enough: In practice, it is never easier to show that some other element is contained in $H$. It is always easier to show $e \in H$.
- The subgroup test with the "non-empty" condition fails for other algebraic structures. For example, a submonoid of a monoid cannot be detected with a non-empty subset closed under products. When you teach "non-empty" for groups, it suggests that "this is how it's done" for groups, and then maybe also for other algebraic structures, maybe with minor modifications. It is better to teach it directly in such a way that the test generalizes to other algebraic structures. Namely, if $G$ is any algebraic structure, a subset $H$ is a substructure precisely iff $H$ is closed under all operations from $G$. When $G$ has constants (that is, $0$-ary functions), this means that $H$ is required to contain all the constants from $G$. This is also why a subring of a ring must contain $0$ and $1$.
- Continuing this, for several other algebraic structures, namely those without constants, substructures *can be empty*. For example, there is an empty semigroup, and it is a subsemigroup of every other semigroup. Teaching the subgroup test with the "non-empty" condition would make some people believe that subsemigroups must be non-empty, and this is wrong. (I have seen this mistake in papers.)
- And finally, questions like this show that beginners may be confused by this "non-empty" condition.
- Likewise, it is never easier to prove $a,b \in H \implies ab^{-1} \in H$ instead of showing $a \in H \implies a^{-1} \in H$ and $a,b \in H \implies ab \in H$ separately.

Summing up, here is the correct* subgroup test:

> If $G$ is a group, then a subset $H \subseteq G$ is a group precisely iff
>
> - $e \in G$
> - For all $a \in H$ we have $a^{-1} \in H$
> - For all $a,b \in H$ we have $ab \in H$

*in the sense: all other formulations are less useful in practice, potentially confusing to beginners and do not generalize.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the arbitrary element in the non-empty set $H$ is *not* necessarily the identity,
but that because this element exists,
we can show that the identity element in $G$ also lies in $H$,
and that the identity in $G$ satisfies the group axioms for it to be the identity in $H$.

It might be more clear if we spell out everything pedantically.
A common definition of a subgroup is as follows:

> An ordered pair $(H, *_H)$ is a subgroup of a group $(G,*_G)$ if $(H,*_H)$ is a group, $H\subseteq G$ and $a*_H b=a*_G b$ for all $a,b\in H$.

The subgroup test states that:

> Let $(G, *_G)$ be a group. Let $H$ be a non-empty subset of $G$.
> Define a binary operation $*_H:H\times H\to G$ by $a*_H b = a*_G b$
> for all $a,b\in H$.
> Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $a *_H b\in H$ for all $a,b\in H$ and $(H,*_H)$ is a subgroup of $(G,*_G)$
> 2. $a^{-1} *_G b\in H$ for all $a,b\in G$, where $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ in $G$, i.e. the unique element $c\in G$ such that $c *_G a = e_G$ ($c$ always exists because $(G,*_G)$ is a group)

The question becomes how we can show $e_G\in H$ and $h *_H e_G=h=e_G *_H h$ for all $h\in H$, so that $e_G$ will be the identity of $(H,*_H)$ once we showed that the pair is a group.
This can be done as follows.
Suppose condition 2 above is true.
Since $H$ is non-empty,
there is some $h_0\in H$.
Since $H\subseteq G$,
we have $h_0\in G$.
Since $(G,*_G)$ is a group,
there is a unique element $k_0\in G$ such that $k_0 *_G h_0=e_G$ (i.e. the inverse of $h_0$ in $(G,*_G)$).
By condition 2,
we have $e_G=k_0 *_G h_0\in H$.
Then $h*_H e_G=h *_G e_G=h=e_G *_G h=e_G *_H h$ for all $h\in H$.